# Postgresql date format with php

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a datetime field that saves data as a string. But I want to save it as a date type.
Is there any date data type in Postgre sql that accepts this kind of date format?
February 1, 2016, 10:17 AM

Comment: Default date-time format for Postgres is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mn:ss.ms`. For example `select '1812-10-23 11:12:13.111'::timestamp` will be accepted everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE` or `TIME` field to save your date, but date variables/ fields in postgres doesnt save format.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html

You have to use postgres function `to_date(text, text)` to convert from string to date

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 1):

You have `TIMESTRAMP` and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

You can have all the information here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html